# Difference between running ElasticSearch as daemon process and using Java Service Wrapper

Tags: java, ubuntu, service, elasticsearch, daemon

I'm working with multiple instances of ElasticSearch installed on a single Ubuntu 14.04 server (using different ports for development purposes), and I was beginning to set up [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) with each one so I can control each instance separately.

However, while digging through some [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/running-elasticsearch.html#running-elasticsearch), I found that it's no problem to start an instance as a daemon process (with `-d`), and then stop the instance with `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_shutdown'`.

My question is, are there significant advantages to setting up the wrapper?  I will add new ES instances now and then, and adding the wrapper seems like a pretty involved process to replicate.  I really only need to be able to start and stop ES in the background--nothing fancy.